# Problema el descargar laravel linux

Tags: laravel, linux

Hola a todos hoy les quiero pedir ayuda porque intente descargar laravel en ubuntu pero me da un error el cual es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Investigué en lugares como [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318709/how-can-i-resolve-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set) pero sigue sin funcionar y también investigue en otro lugares, esta es la imagen de mis archivos **.ini**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo no si se tenga que ver pero por si es que si este es el comando que estoy usando: `composer create-project laravel/laravel proyecto "8.0.*" --prefer-dist` .

No he podido encontrar el error entonces agrezco si me dicen que estoy haciendo mal. Gracias :).

Comment: bienvenid@ a SO! Creo que el error es bastante claro: `te falta instalar algunas dependencias`. Como nota aparte: no pongas screenshots si no hacen falta. El primer screenshot, pon el texto en la pregunta (si no sabes formatearlo, no hay problema... otras personas lo formatearían y podrías mirar como hacerlo luego)... y el segundo screenshot, seguramente con un `ls` podrías tener un listado en texto.

Comment: @eftshift0 perdón que pregunte pero ¿qué dependencias en específico? o me puedes dar mas detalles por favor

Comment: No tengo experiencia instalando laravel pero creo que una de las cosas que no tienes es `phpunit`.... lo de `ext-dom` no estaría seguro a qué se refiere. Lo busqué con `apt-cache search ext-dom` y no salió nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debes instalar **php-xml**

```
sudo apt install php-xml
```

Comment: Gracias ese era el problema